# This year is the fifth year

Tags: present-perfect

> It's been five years since he moved to America.

Five years ago, he moved to America, and he still lives there today.

Can I change it to

> This year is the fifth year it has been since he moved to America.

Comment: This is the fifth year since he moved...

Comment: Thank you. When you use *since*, I think the most appropriate tense is present perfect. Is the present simple acceptable? Is my original sentence *This year is the fifth year it has been since he moved to America* correct?

Comment: You have to take out "it has been". *This year is the fifth year since...* is clumsy because of the repetition but grammatically correct.  *This year is the fifth since...* is also  grammatically correct but *This is the fifth year since he moved...* is better.

Comment: What tense you use with *since* depends on the context. In your sentences, yes, the present perfect is the correct tense because you are referring to a state in the past that is still **continuing in the present**. But in other contexts we could have the perfect or the past perfect. We can't use *since* with the simple present when *since* is used to refer to time. We could use *since* with the simple present when  *since* is used as a conjunction synonym of *because*.

Comment: Without "it has been", I feel it isn't grammatical. In another sentence, I see "it has been" is used: Today's top temperature is the lowest it has been since last Friday.

Comment: This is the fifth year since he moved... since is used to refer to time. So, it doesn't work.

Comment: *Today's top temperature is the lowest it has been since last Friday* and *This year is the fifth year since he moved* are different structures. It is either *This is the 5th year since...* **or** *It has  been five years since...*

Comment: I can see I missed one of your points and wasn't clear enough. *It has been five years*: present perfect. ... *since he moved*: perfect because he moved at one point in the past (he's settled now!). **But**  ... *since he's lived in America* because he moved five years ago and he is still living there.

Comment: Can you please explain why present simple, instead of present perfect, is used in this sentence: This is the 5th year since he moved to America. Since doesn't mean because in this sentence, in my opinion.

Comment: *He moved* is the preterit not the present simple. According to context the perterit can be used after since, as you used it in your sentence.

Comment: I meant *This is the 5th year* is present simple, not present perfect. Why does the present simple work, if we use "since" in the sentence?

Comment: @Stephen The event referred to by "since" is "he moved", not "is". Counting from the year he moved, this is the fifth year; this is the fifth year since he moved. P.S. this kind of phrase frequently prompts off-by-one errors. The speaker often ends up clarifying by stating "It's been four years, so this is the fifth" and then, when confusion inevitably still reigns, you end up specifying the year he moved :)

Comment: But yes, you certainly need to drop "it has been", as None wrote. It strikes us as nonsensical since it doesn't "be a year" every year as a discrete action. What happens is that "a year passes". Hence you *could* say "This is the fifth year that has passed since he moved" — but it would still be redundant. (And seemingly indicate one more year than without it!)

Comment: @Luke Sawczak Sorry, I don't understand this part of your last reply: *It strikes us as nonsensical since it doesn't "be a year" every year as a discrete action. What happens is that "a year passes"*.

Comment: My experience with English is that, the since-clause usually uses the past simple tense, and the main clause uses the present perfect tense. But, in the sentence *This is the 5th year since he moved to America*, the main clause uses the present simple. I don't understand the reason.

Comment: @Stephen The main clause can use any tense. Past: It was the fifth year since he had moved out [notice the relative clause in pluperfect]. Present: It is the fifth year since he moved out. Future: It will be the fifth year since he moved out. Anterior future: It will have been the fifth year since he moved out. Conditional: It would have been the fifth year since he moved out. Re: "it has been", I meant that "it is [year]" is not a discrete action in English, so "the fifth year it has been" sounds very unnatural. Whereas "a year passed" is discrete, so "the fifth year that has passed" is fine.

Comment: Maybe this (*This is the 5th year since he moved to America*) is a exception to the rule. Generally, we use the present perfect for the main clause, for example, He's never seen his old friends since he moved to America. We can't use other tenses for the main clause in this sentence.

Comment: *I meant that "it is [year]" is not a discrete action in English, ... Whereas "a year passed" is discrete*...Sorry, what is discrete action?

Comment: @Stephen Something that can be clearly differentiated from another action; something that is linked to a specific point in time; something that can be counted. In other European languages, one tends to use the "imperfect" form for non-discrete actions. Statives like "is" are not likely to be discrete. For instance, to throw a ball is discrete. "He threw the ball five times in the last sixty seconds." But to be sad is not. "He was sad five times in the last sixty seconds" is odd. Similarly, "It is (year)" is non-discrete and hence "The fifth year it has been" sounds wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand what discrete action is. But *it has been* works in this sentence: *Today's top temperature is the lowest it has been since last Friday*. Why does it work?